# celery worker raise sock setsockopt TCP_SYNCNT [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sockets, celery

I am using `celery` with `rabbitmq`, But I recently get this error `sock.setsockopt(SOL_TCP, opt, val), [Errno 22] Invalid argument`,
detail,

```
{1: 1, 2: 16396, 3: 0, 4: 60, 5: 10, 6: 9, 7: 0, 8: 30, 9: 0, 10: 81059, 12: 1}
(6, 1, 1)
(6, 2, 16396)
(6, 3, 0)
(6, 4, 60)
(6, 5, 10)
(6, 6, 9)
(6, 7, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 535, in apply_async
    **options
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 737, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 558, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 527, in _ensured
    errback and errback(exc, 0)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 419, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 414, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 515, in _ensured
    reraise_as_library_errors=False,
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 405, in ensure_connection
    callback)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 333, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 261, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 802, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 757, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 130, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 294, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 122, in connect
    self.socket_settings, self.read_timeout, self.write_timeout,
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 174, in _init_socket
    self._set_socket_options(socket_settings)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 205, in _set_socket_options
    self.sock.setsockopt(SOL_TCP, opt, val)
  File "/app/pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

> `(6, 7, 0)` is the output of `print(SOL_TCP, opt, val)` which I add in `_set_socket_options`

after referring to `_socket.pi`, I get this:

- `6`, `SOL_TCP = 6`
- `7`, `TCP_SYNCNT = 7` (I think...)
- `0`, val

that all I know, I assume that it has something with system setting, it work well with other system with same code and package.But I knows little about `TCP_SYNCNT`, any help is appreciated!

BTW, Here are my environments

- celery 4.0.2 (latentcall)
- rabbitmq-server-3.6.6-1.el6.noarch
- erlang-19.1.6-1.el6.x86_64
- CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
- python2.7.11 with pyenv

pip freeze

```
amqp==2.1.4
billiard==3.5.0.2
celery==4.0.2
chardet==3.0.4
Django==1.10.3
django-redis==4.8.0
djangorestframework==3.6.3
httplib2==0.10.3
kombu==4.0.2
netifaces==0.10.6
psutil==5.2.2
py==1.4.34
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyftpdlib==1.5.2
pyrabbit==1.1.0
pytest==3.0.6
pytz==2017.2
redis==2.10.5
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.10.0
vine==1.1.3
xlrd==1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by set `net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 1`, somebody set it to `0` which maybe means never send `syn` before `ESTABLISHED`.